# Override shortcode which defined as PHP class

Tags: wordpress, overriding, shortcode

How to override shortcode if it defined as a class?

So I have some shortcode which defined as Class with methods and I faced with a problem how to override it?

Sorry, I can't provide a code because can be illegal.

As an idea was override class and assign to my own shortcode to it. but doesn't how to do this too.

Thanks.

PS If needs more information please tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the shortcode. Use the WordPress core function `remove_shortcode( $tag );` in your own code. `$tag` shiuld be the string used in `add_shortcode()` in the class code. Read more at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_shortcode.

Once you've removed the shortcode you can add your own which replaces it. Possibly by extending the original class in your own code.

Comment: Almost all time it defined as a function, But in my case, it's a class. I tried to override it as functional, but didn't helped or maybe something miss. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: Almost all time it defined as a function, But in my case, it's a class. I tried to override it as functional, but didn't helped or maybe something miss. So I removed existing shortcode and created a new one.  Also override class and in my function.php made add_shortcode('my_new_shortcode', 'My_New_Class');

doesn't work.